# Are there huge differences between Safari versions on Windows and Mac OS?

Tags: browsers, windows, safari, mac

I have recently engaged in a conversation where were people defending that you should test your websites on Safari for Windows and on Safari for Mac, because they're very different.
As a webmaster, there is this constant concern on having my web applications or websites running on every browser, but I don't have a Mac available for me to try the performance and/or rendering engine.

Long story short: are there huge differences between Safari for Windows and Mac? Does anyone use Safari for Windows as their main browser and can tell me if it's important for me to test on it too?

Comment: As a cross-reference, this [has been asked previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308305/differences-between-safari-for-windows-and-safari-for-mac) on Stack Overflow, with several responses. Note that's old, but it might be worth checking, if any of those items are of interest. I wouldn't generally consider most of them "huge," though.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference I have noticed is with form elements such as dropdowns and input boxes.

These can be manipulated easily on Windows Safari (e.g. padding, rounded corners, line-height) but Mac Safari does not adhere to much of this CSS on it's forms.

I've also noticed further differences between 'desktop' Safari and mobile Safari - i.e. in an iPad.

(Sorry I can't provide any screenshots to demonstrate this but I'm not in the office at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

One to remember is the difference in Mac's rendering of fonts, and that seems to be at it's most extreme in Safari.

I just took these screenshots on my Mac, and you can see that Safari renders the line a bit bigger. Over lots of text, this can have a significant effect on the size of divs.

I don't have Windows to hand, so if somebody else could post a screengrab of Safari on Windows that would show the difference.

edit: added Win7 images.

**Firefox (Mac)**
[image: Mac Firefox]

**Safari (Mac)**
[image: Mac Safari]

**Safari (Win7)**
[image: Win Safari]

**Firefox (Win7)**
[image: Win Firefox]

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but have you forgotten the screenshots? I'm not seeing any link.

Comment: @astro11 - the images are above. Not very obviously because they are screenshots of text but they are underneath the browser names with the 'These can be manipulated easily...' text from John's answer.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I'm using Safari for Windows and thought it was simple text instead of images. Thanks for the screenshots, they are very useful.

Comment: @astro11 Was there a significant difference between Mac Safari and Windows Safari with the font rendering?

Comment: Well, I think so. Can you tell me which font you used on your Safari image? Was it pure text on a blank HTML? I'll try to reproduce the same thing and then post the result image here.

Comment: @astro11 It's Helvetica, which is typically used on a Mac instead of Arial.

Comment: @astro11 PS - it's just a screengrab of the second paragraph in John's answer to this question.

Comment: I didn't notice it was just a screengrab. I edited your post (under revision) adding the images for win7 safari and firefox. There is a very significant difference between them.